# Suitable 3rd party libraries to use on android video editing app development?

Tags: android, react-native, libraries

I am planning to develop an android app for video editing using react-native.
Example: Video cropping, Video rotating, Video frame editing mainly.
I want to know suitable and best libraries for the development also i would like to know if there are any better frameworks to do that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One of the most popular library for video editing is [FFMPEG](https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android)

it is widely used by the developer and big company like youtube also some media players used it.

you can also find another library from GitHub